# Making a QGIS plugin public for users

Tags: qgis, python, osgeo

I created a Python plugin in QGIS and I want to make it public, so that any user could download and use it

I serached in https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ , but to upload the plugin , I have to have an OSGEO acount. I looked in https://id.osgeo.org/ldap/create, apparentelly I can not create it the acount as usual, I sent the request to mantra-request@osgeo.org but it is taking too much time.

Is there any other way to upload my plugin ?

Comment: You could create a zip file, host it somewhere and users could download and install the zip file https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins.html#the-install-from-zip-tab